# Blank information after merge

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, heatmap, shapefile

**R version 3.2.1**

I'm following [this article on how to create Heat Maps](http://spatialanalysis.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/james_cheshire_ggplot_intro_blog.pdf)
and downloaded the required files (just need help with the logic)

This works

```
setwd("D:/GIS/london")
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(gpclib)

sport <- readShapeLines("london_sport.shp")
```

When I run

```
names(sport)
```

I get normal output, i.e.

```
[1] "ons_label"  "name"       "Partic_Per" "Pop_2001"
```

And when I print sport

```
print(sport)
```

I get this (showing first 6 lines)

```
                                   geometry ons_label                   name Partic_Per Pop_2001
0  MULTILINESTRING((541177.7 173555.7 ...))      00AF                Bromley       21.7   295535
1  MULTILINESTRING((522957.6 178071.3 ...))      00BD   Richmond upon Thames       26.6   172330
2  MULTILINESTRING((505114.9 184625.1 ...))      00AS             Hillingdon       21.5   243006
3  MULTILINESTRING((552108.3 194151.8 ...))      00AR               Havering       17.9   224262
4  MULTILINESTRING((519370.8 163657.4 ...))      00AX   Kingston upon Thames       24.4   147271
5  MULTILINESTRING((525554.3 166815.8 ...))      00BF                 Sutton       19.3   179767
6  MULTILINESTRING((513062.8 178187.2 ...))      00AT               Hounslow       16.9   212352
```

So far everything looks normal. I understand the next few lines, to create plot points

```
p <- ggplot(sport@data, aes(Partic_Per, Pop_2001))
p + geom_point(aes(color="Partic_Per", size = "Pop_2001")) + geom_text(size=2, aes(label=name))
gpclibPermit()
```

Then we make the shape file (sport) into a data frame

```
sport_geom <- fortify(sport, region="ons_label")
```

And when I execute `head(sport_geom)` I get

```
      long      lat order piece group id
1 541177.7 173555.7     1     1   0.1  0
2 541872.2 173305.8     2     1   0.1  0
3 543441.5 171429.9     3     1   0.1  0
4 544361.6 172379.2     4     1   0.1  0
5 546662.4 170451.9     5     1   0.1  0
6 548187.1 170582.3     6     1   0.1  0
```

Then the command to merge data, **where the problem arises**

```
sport_geom <- merge (sport_geom, sport@data, by.x = "id", by.y = "ons_label")
```

When I go according to the document and print `by.`, the only values that pop up are `by.data.frame` and `by.default`

[image]

And when I execute `head(sport_geom)`, the data is blank!!!

```
[1] id         long       lat        order      piece      group     
name       Partic_Per Pop_2001   <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

What am I missing and how to troubleshoot this?

Perhaps this is an error in the document (this is the simplest tutorial I can find on Heat Maps), because I was troubleshooting another error for the past hour.

Please help!!!!!! I know it's long, but it's the best I could do to explain the issue and possibly reproduce it.

If you need links to download the stuff, I'll get it for you.

Comment: does this work `merge (sport_geom, sport@data, by.x = "id", by.y = "ons_label")`? Are you merging twice, I don't understand. tab completion is just giving you suggestions, you don't have to use them. It doesn't make sense to merge by functions like `by.data.frame`

Comment: @rawr I am not merging twice and the statement `sport_geom <- merge (sport_geom, sport@data, by.x = "id", by.y = "ons_label")` does work. The problem is `sport_geom` becomes empty.

Comment: well `id` and `ons_label ` need to have overlapping ids. `id` is 0,0,... and `ons_label` is 00AF, 00BD, ...

Comment: @rawr Oh dear! So this documentation is wrong ........

Comment: @rawr I found another website from this person, perhaps that has corrected code .... http://spatial.ly/2013/12/introduction-spatial-data-ggplot2/

Comment: look [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/intro-spatial-rl.pdf) on page 22. the two data sets have similar ids after running the `rownames <-` line. looks like that was left out of the tutorial you're using, but that might not fix the problem for the data you're using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81571/discussion-between-sohni-mahiwal-and-rawr).